# Reading and Writing to a SQL Database from multiple processes and threads

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing

I building an application that continuously fetches weather data from an API for multiple cities and reads/writes this data to a SQL (MySQL) database using multiple processes and threads in Python. I am relatively new at this.

Let's say there are two processes. Each process spawns N threads, one thread per city. Each thread executes the same logic for a different city.

Thread 1 in Process 1 grabs data from an API for New York every 60 seconds and writes it to SQL Table X. Thread 2 in Process 2 grabs data for Los Angeles every 60 seconds and writes it to SQL Table X.

Table X has the following attributes: `Record Index (Int), City (Varchar), Processed (Boolean), Some Data (Int)`. When a thread in Process 1 writes data to Table X, the `Processed` attribute is marked as `False` by default.

Moving onto Process 2...Thread 1 in Process 2 grabs unprocessed data (all records where `Processed=False`) from Table X for New York every 60 seconds, copies it to Table Y, and marks this data as processed in Table X. Thread 2 in Process 2 grabs unprocessed data from Table X for Los Angeles every 60 seconds, copies it to Table Y, and marks this data as processed in Table X.

I use SQLAlchemy to read and write to the database. I initialize a new engine in each process via:

`engine = create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@{host}/{database}')`

I execute SQL statements via:

```
with engine.begin() as connection:
     connection.execute(sql_statement)
```

The issue I have is that I need to block Process 1 from adding new data to Table X for New York (for example) until Process 2 finishes 1.) copying unprocessed data for New York to Table Y and 2.) marks the copied data as Processed=`True` in Table X. Otherwise, it is possible that new data could be added to Table X in Process 1 and marked as processed in Process 2 without actually being copied to Table Y.

I believe that I could use a lock (multiprocessing.Lock()) to solve this issue, but in addition to blocking threads processing New York across all processes, it would also block threads processing Los Angeles (and any other city for that matter) across all processes.

I could switch the architecture such that each process is responsible for handling a different city, and each thread runs different logic (data acquisition, data processing). Essentially, this would be the opposite of what it is now. However, a lot of the processing that I need to do is CPU bound so I believe that this could be less efficient.

Is using a multiprocessing lock the best way to resolve this issue? What are other alternatives?

Comment: Maybe [SELECT ... FOR UPDATE](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/selectable.html?highlight=for_update#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.GenerativeSelect.with_for_update)?

Comment: Depending on what your actual data and queries are "Otherwise, it is possible that new data could be added to Table X in Process 1 and marked as processed in Process 2 without actually being copied to Table Y" can be avoided without much locking at all, I think. Again, it would depend on the data and the queries. If that's not the case, SQL DBMS usually offer a wide variety of locking and isolation mechanisms, from row level locking to advisory locks.

Answer (score 1):

Few things I can think of real quick, just to give you some ideas

1. A file lock (at a known location with a name that can be derived from the context you are operating). There are libraries that offer you file lock primitives (filelock)
2. Implement a locking primitive in DB at the level of granularity you want. The primitive could be an integer. Both processes must synchronize on this. It is possible that both read the primitive at the same time, increment it and try to write it back , but only one will succeed in writing - you have to handle this

I had a qn: You mention that you are doing CPU bound tasks. How effective is the threading model in that case within each of the process?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Regarding your question, I do not know how effective the threading model is yet because I have only tested the app with up to three cities.